# How to change values in a dictionary to lists instead of strings

Tags: python, dictionary

I have:

```
dict1 = {'usa' : '10', 'japan' : '20', 'canada' :'30'}
```

And I'm trying to change the values to show as lists, like:

```
dict1 = {'usa' : [10], 'japan' : [20], 'canada' : [30]}
```

I've tried iterating over the values in the dictionary but the output hasn't changed...

```
for v in dict1.values():
    v = list(v)
```

Comment: It does not change because `v` is available only by value, not by reference. You did not change the original dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply iterating through the dictionary:

```
for i in dict1:
    dict1[i] = [int(dict1[i])]

print dict1
```

which will give you:

```
{'canada': [30], 'japan': [20], 'usa': [10]}
```

Also you can use dictionary comprehensions, (as suggested by iCodez), but for a person new to python this might be harder to grasp, also shorter.

Comment: also, your chess site looks pretty cool, i'm probably going to make an account!

Comment: @user4196702 you welcome. If you will have some suggestions or idea for new features - please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is not working because your loop is just repeatedly reassigning the name `v` to `list(v)`.  It is not actually changing the values inside `dict1`.

The easiest way to do what you want is to use a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
>>> dict1 = {'usa' : '10', 'japan' : '20', 'canada' :'30'}
>>> {k:[int(v)] for k, v in dict1.items()}
{'japan': [20], 'canada': [30], 'usa': [10]}
>>>
```

Note that in Python 2.x, you should do `dict1.iteritems()` to avoid creating an unnecessary list.